# How can I download steam games files on android?

Tags: steam

I am trying to download the files from a windows game from steam on my android phone.

I don't want to remotely start a download on my PC but download the game directly to my phone. 
At home I have limited 300gb of bandwidth, but my friend has unlimited internet, I can't take my PC to his house but I can take my phone and download the files on it, and later transfer them to my PC.

It need to download them only using the phone, not a PC, so I don't need to use my phone as a portable storage. I need it as a download machine. I.e. I want download game files to my phone via my friend's unlimited internet connection, then I want to transfer them to my PC at home where I'm going to use them instead of actually downloading game via my limited connection.

Is there any way of doing this? I am even open to writing my own app if there is an API open to use for android.

Comment: What game? As far as I am aware, Windows Games aren't available through Steam.

Comment: @TimmyJim for honor is free now, lets say i want to download it but on my phone. at home i am limited by bandwidth and that's why i don't download on my pc

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but you basically want to download the files to your phone so you can transfer them to your PC later?

Comment: @Ash yes that is exactly what i want to do

Comment: I don't think what you want to do is possible, nor can we help you write some sort of program to allow for it.  The best thing you can try doing is setting up a mobile hot spot with your phone, connect your PC to it, and download the game onto your PC directly using the mobile hot spot.  That way, you would still use your phone's data connection.

Comment: @TimmyJim i feel like this needs context. At home i am limited by 300gb of bandwidth, but my friend has unlimited internet, i can't take my PC to his house but i can take my phone and download the files there and later transfer them to my pc

Comment: You aren't making your question clear enough.  If you **are not** trying to use your phones mobile data to perform the download, then you are effectively trying to use it as a portable storage device, such as a flash drive.  In that event, you should be able to transfer the files to your phone via the USB cable for the phone, and again transfer them back onto your PC. You will need to make sure you have enough storage to handle all the files.

Comment: @TimmyJim I am trying to somehow download the files of a game on my phone's storage or a portable hard drive and later transfer them to my pc. I need to download them directly to my phone without using anything else but my phone. that means it has to be my phone, not download them from a computer and use my phone to store them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible in the future using [Wine](https://wiki.winehq.org/Android), but I just spent an hour or so trying using Wine 3.14 for Android and could not get [steamcmd](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD).exe to run.

I did not try the real Steam client, though I highly doubt it would be usable if it even did run unless you have a tablet or are willing to use [Steam's terminal commands](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Command_Line_Options#Steam_.28Windows.29) to *attempt* to get it to work well enough to install the game =\

---

It *may* currently be possible using [Limbo](https://limboemulator.weebly.com), a [QEMU](https://www.qemu.org)-like app for Android, but I really didn't even know this existed until a few minutes ago. It's also going to take me a long while to try to get anything to happen there -- I truly hate installing Linux, my phone isn't rooted so it may not work as easily as a rooted device (though Termux + NodeJS are doing amazing), and I probably don't have enough space for an OS install with updates + steamcmd + even a small game on here either with currently less than 4GB of space (but I will try to make space).

I know Linux installs without a GUI can be very small, but I like to have some free space and they do take a bit. And just for fun: Wine on Android is only about 130MB when installed from it's 123MB download (as of 3.14).

Edit: Limbo sucked. [UserLAnd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tech.ula) seems promising as you have root by default, but after literally hours of trying I just gave up. multiverse, multiarch, running as root, installing & running from root. No matter which sets of directions I follow it continues to fail, possibly because it's Ubuntu 18 & everything is for around 16 or lower. [GNURoot Debian](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gnuroot.debian) may also work just because it's got root.

Comment: Wow, that's amazing. thank you for trying to help me. Currently my phone isn't rooted so I'll try the solutions that don't require root. If none of that works I'm gonna use a android TV box i got lying around that is already rooted

Comment: Also, did you manage to download the file for limbo? I've tried it and it said it has been deleted

Comment: No problem :) I'm a bit of a Steam nerd and my PC isn't doing well, so I was also interested in this idea. Ah, yes, sorry -- that file is hosted via Google Drive and the owner seems to have removed it, but the version just before that did download & install fine. Unfortunately I never even got it to boot once, and honestly I still have no idea what I'm doing there. I've used VirtualBox *many* times, but that skill did not translate well, lol.

Comment: The biggest issue using SteamCmd is really some incompatibility it seems -- even with proper setup using a version installed through either curl or apt it gives an error on (IIRC) Line 20: ulimit - permission denied (limit of open files; already unlimited) and Line 37: ./Linux32/steamcmd - permission denied. This also happens while running as root or using sudo, and occurred on both Debian and Ubuntu through UserLAnd. I'll give GNURoot a shot today and edit in results for that too. If you'd like we can chat about this in PMs -- we can probably get it, but it's definitely going to be hard, lol.

Comment: @DavidAnastasov And another possible, but unlikely, future way to accomplish this which was just released recently -- [v86](https://github.com/copy/v86). An x86 emulator for Electron/browser, and should also be possible to setup with pure NodeJS though that's not in any examples. XP won't be working with Steam for long though (Jan 1st, 2018 support will be dropped, IIRC); Vista too. I did try to email you, from me @ yahoo dot com, but the response may have gotten lost in my spam folder -- I'll check again. If possible, please resend your response (if you did already).

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to download Steam games directly to your phone. Your phone can only act as a storage device (not as a downloader like you described), just like a USB stick or an external hard drive.

Your only option if you want to download the game from your friend's house is to use his computer and transfer the files manually to your phone, but it would be a better idea to use a USB stick or an external hard drive.

A workaround to your download cap in your home's network, is to start the download at the end of you billable month to take the remaining data left in your data cap, and finish the download at a later date.

Comment: At home i am limited by 300gb of bandwidth, but my friend has unlimited internet, i can't take my PC to his house but i can take my phone and download the files there and later transfer them to my pc, i am not trying to use my phones mobile data for downloading the files

Comment: Can't you just take a USB stick or external hard drive and download the game from your friend's computer?

Comment: I could do it but i'm looking for an alternative as his computer is old, the hard drive is slow and let's say a 50gb game transferring trough usb 2.0 takes hours and hours. while if i could do it directly to my phone i wouldn't have to deal with all that. A 7gb file took 50 minutes to transfer from his pc to my phone

Comment: @DavidAnastasov then plug your phone in his pc and save the files directly to your phone.

Comment: @0xFF why did you remove your answer about using steamCMD with a terminal ?

Comment: @DavidAnastasov He removed his comment because SteamCMD cannot work on Android (closed source and not the right processor architecture)

Comment: @TheBird956 what about using something like Linux deploy to install lets say kali linux and use the terminal to load steamCMD there and download the files that way. would that work ?

Comment: @DavidAnastasov I don't know how Busybox works, but I doubt it would fix it because android phones run a ARM processor and SteamCMD require x86 or x86_64 processors

Comment: @DavidAnastasov To make it work on a ARM processor you would need to recompile SteamCMD, but you can't do that since the source code is not available to the public

Comment: I'm sorry i mixed up the apps. I was speaking about Linux Deploy. it can install linux on your android phone and use it like a desktop

Comment: @DavidAnastasov It doesn't change much. The main problem is not the OS it is running on, it's the hardware

Comment: @TheBird956 yeah but steamcmd is made to run on linux. does it matter if its linux on arm, i don't believe steamcmd does anything with the hardware, its just downloading the files. correct me if im wrong

Comment: @DavidAnastasov It's not something specific to SteamCMD. When the software is compiled, instructions are written for a specific CPU architecture. Those instructions tell the CPU what to do, and they are different depending or your CPU architecture. Here is a good StackOverflow question about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794460/how-does-the-arm-architecture-differ-from-x86

Comment: @TheBird956 Some Android tablets do use Intel architecture processors, but yeah for the most part they're ARM of course. And thank you for the reminder as I hadn't considered that. Still strange to get a permission denied error instead of something about not being able to run the executable or code (of steamcmd, not .sh).